# How to start two services or activities from one BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to start two services on reboot of the device using only one `Broadcastreceiver`. But only one service is called.

Here is my receiver:

```
public class FirstReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
      private static final String TAG8 = "Mytag";

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {    
           Log.i(TAG8, "Restarting App after boot");
           Intent myServiceInent = new Intent(context, FirstReciever.class);
           context.startService(myServiceInent);
           Intent myServiceInent1 = new Intent(context, DbService.class);
           context.startService(myServiceInent1);
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it will start a service
`Intent myServiceInent = new Intent(context, FirstReciever.class);

           context.startService(myServiceInent);`

Comment: you have given the reference of your Receiver not of a service...

Comment: Hey thanx for your support ..but by mistake I wrote FirstReciever.class ...but actually I have FirstService.class ...and I want to start both the service from this Receiver after reboot..So in that case what is your suggestion?

Comment: start a single service and start another service from first one...

Comment: okey, I will try with that one.

Answer (score 0):

To start an Activity use:
`startActivity(intent);`
To Start a Service use:
`startService(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

first of all look at this.

```
Intent myServiceInent = new Intent(context, FirstReciever.class);

           context.startService(myServiceInent);
```

you have given the reference of your `FirstReciever.class`, that should be a service.

and if that doesn't work than start a single service and start another service from first one...